# Translate glmer (lme4) model specification into MCMCglmm

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, glmm, lme4-nlme

I am having some computational trouble estimating the following model with the glmer function in lme4:

```
glmer(Y ~ x1*x2 + x2*x3 + (1+x1+x2|class) + (1|obs), family=poisson)
```

- where `class` refers to my groupings,
- `obs` refers to observation (because I would like to an observation-level random effect).

I'd like to try the `MCMCglmm` package (without deep knowledge of MCMC unfortunately), but cannot figure out how to specify the random effects. So far, my draft command is:

```
MCMCglmm(fixed = Y ~ x1*x2 + x2*x3, 
  random = ~ class + x1:class + x2:class + obs, family="poisson")
```

Could you please help me specify the model?

Comment: Here is a detailed tutorial describing how to use MCMCglmm and how to implement lme4-style LMMs: https://github.com/tmalsburg/MCMCglmm-intro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MCMCglmm documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/MCMCglmm.pdf): "*Multiple random terms can be passed using the + operator*" (as you already do). Having said that you appear to be defining multiple random intercepts and no random slopes.

In general you need to use a syntax similar to `~us(1+x1):x2`, where `x2` is your discrete variables (for the intercepts), `x1` is your continuous variable (for the slopes) and `us` denotes an unstructured random covariance. You may want to check other covariance structures (eg. `idh` for an identity one). Please check the chapters 3 and 4 in dealing with *Categorical Random Interactions* and *Continuous Random Interactions* respectively in the related [MCMCglmm Course Notes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf). The general [overview](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/Overview.pdf) document is also very helpful (and more concise). I cannot emphasise enough how helpful these notes are, using `MCMCglmm` without reading them would be nearly impossible for me.

I suspect you want a structure similar to:  `~us(1+x1+x2):class + obs` but please check this twice before using it. Note that a global intercept is not fitted by default for variance structure models so you need the `+1` that was otherwise redundant for `lmer`.

Good luck specifying your priors! :D

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, MCMCglmm poisson models include an observation-level random effect by default, as the author seems to believe that over-dispersion is the regular case, not the exception. In the manual it is called *additive* over-dispersion. In MCMCglmm summaries it is called the *unit* effect